# Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES ---crosscompiling toolchain

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

Iam trying to build a cross compiler using this tutorial:
http://wiki.osdev.org/OS_Specific_Toolchain

after succesfully building binutils,all-gcc,newlib

I am getting an error in the last part of make in build-gcc

```
checking for shl_load... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:8970: recipe for target `configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/build-gcc'
Makefile:870: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help...

Comment: What build target have you set for the compiler that you are compiling?

Comment: the target is i586-pc-myos....
i have also edited many files in source package as in the above mentioned tutorial.....

Comment: unfortunately i did not....sorry..

Comment: check your equivalent of the file gcc/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/config.log for more info.  NB that GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES basically means "autoconf determines that the C compiler can not link" ref: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16371

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you configure command options. But if you have given **--enable-language=c** change it to **--enable-languages=c**. Or may be you are compiling bootstrap with languages c and c++. In which case this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when attempting to build a cross compiler for ARM.  Eventually, switched to using [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/).  It is a script that greatly simplifies the process.  It worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone else I have a warning and a work-around:

*Warning: you can get OP's error by attempting to blindly build a native toolchain from LFS instructions or messing around with `--with-sysroot`*

Always check your `./config.log` first. If you see an error related to something like "can't find stdio.h" or some other missing *.h file, chances are your `GCC` has no idea where to find your libraries/headers.

OP could force it to find them by overriding the `CC` environment variable with "`-B`" and "`-I`" flags.

e.g.

```
CC="${LFS_TGT}-gcc -B${LFS}/lib -I${LFS}/include" \
"../gcc-0.0.0/libstdc++-v3/configure"
```